# Automatically choose between log and linear scale on graph axis

Tags: algorithm, math, graph

I have a web application written in Java. It has a scatterplot page, using the JFreeChart library that the user can send results to. The results are pairs of Doubles and do not belong to any specific distribution. They can be very skewed or not depending on what the user has selected to plot.

Currently the user has a drop down to select whether they want a logarithmic or linear Y-Axis. I also have a piece of code that disables the logarithmic Y-Axis option if the results contain any Doubles less than or equal to zero.

The client has submitted a feature request "Make web application automatically choose the correct type of Y-Axis (log vs linear)". Is this even possible? Does anybody know of suitable algorithms to test the results with that would suggest one axis type over the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using log scale is appropriate for graphs that grow exponentially.

You can check for exponential growth by plotting it in a logarithmic scale and see if it looks linear.

See [Test for exponential growth](http://mathbench.umd.edu/modules/popn-dynamics_meningitis/page12.htm).

Comment: That link is useful, but relies on a human looking at the shape of the graph. I was hoping for a mathematical test that could be run against the results

Comment: Ah, so then you use the method of [least squares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares) to get an approximate line, then you see how far from the line each dot is. If they are above a certain threshold, you go for linear scale. Otherwise, you do log scale.

Comment: I've used least squares before. Am I to assume then that the best algorithm would be 
1) run least squares against the results and store the r^2 value,  
 2) take the log of the results and run least squares against that and store the r^2 value  
3) if the r^2 value for the first one is higher, use a linear axis, else use a logarithmic axis?

Comment: Hmm.. That may work fine. My initial suggestion was to start at your step 2 (log the to-be-plotted values), and then, using least squares approximate a straight line to the logged result, and then check if any of the points are too far off the straight line. If they're close, use log scale, if they're far off, use linear scale.

Comment: @Ralph, did it work out for you? (If so, please consider [marking this answer as accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) so we get a closure on this thread.)

Comment: Unfortunately I've been moved onto other work. I'm hoping to get back to this soon and this is my intended solution as it looks easiest to implement. Will mark as accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could try looking at the statistics of the height differences Y_{i+1}-Y_{i} (resp. log (Y_{i+1})-log(Y_i)).

More precisely  I assume you are plotting the set of pairs (X_i, Y_i) and that you have ordered them by X-coordinate : X_1 <= X_2 <= .. <=X_n. Also let Y_min and Y_max be the maximal and minimal values of Y. Of course we need Y_min >0.

Then you could compute the standard deviation of Y_{i+1}-Y_{i} divided by (Y_max - Y_min) (resp. the standard deviation of log(Y_{i+1})-log(Y_{i}) divided by (log(Y_max)-log(Y_min) ) and go for the smaller of the two.

I have never tested this but I assume this would select the scale where the curve looks the most linear, which is usually what one wants. It is also quite fast. If your datas are very noisy you may want to refine on this.